# How to write that you will drop a function's argument from the notation?

Tags: expressions, conjunctions, writing, mathematics

I am trying to express the following idea: I have L(t) and F(t) to denote that L and F are functions of t. Now, for the rest of the text, I want to use a shorter notation, that is L and F instead of L(t) and F(t).
My attempt:

> For notational convenience we will drop the notation for dependence on t and L ...

Could you please help me in adding, in this same sentence, the fact that "we also drop the notation for dependence between t and F ?

P.S.:Please don't hesitate to edit the title to give a better description to my question.

Comment: If you describe once that L and F are functions of one variable, t, then you don't *usually* need to justify omitting the parentheses.  Something like "Let L and F be functions of t:  L=L(t), F=F(t)." and just keep using L and F afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I would just say "for convenience, we drop the input notation t", or "...the notation for dependence on t". It is implied you mean for both functions L and F.

Answer (score 1):

*Omit* is the word you want, it means "supposed to be there but not included."

*Leave out* will work as well and sound a bit less technical.

> ... for convenience, we'll omit the input notation the notation for dependence on t and L ...

Comment: The original poster's example seems formal.  "we'll" might not be formal enough.

Comment: I think present tense works here "we omit...".